# Need Regex to Ignore First Line & Start On Next Line

Tags: regex, parsing

I am needing a Regex code to start after the `Lead Alert:` then ignore that first line and start on the next one finishing it before the word `Recommend`.

Here is my code and screen shots:

```
/(?<=Lead Alert:)([\s\S]*?)(?!Recommend)/
```

You'll see the line breaks after `Lead Alert` and before `Recommend`. Want to remove that and get the data in between?

[Regex Code with Data Extracting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfXTK.png)

[Another Example Thats a bit Clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5OnV.png)

Comment: Try `LEAD ALERT:.*\n([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*Recommend)`

Comment: I think this is the one. Nice. Thanks

Comment: Please do not link to images. Doing so forces readers to manually copy code and/or data they want to use for testing. Moreover, links have a habit of breaking, often turning questions into space debris.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Lead Alert:.*\n([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*Recommend)
```

*Details*:

- `Lead Alert:` - a literal text
- `.*` - the rest of the current line
- `\n` - a newline, LF char
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*Recommend)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and `Recommend` string.